# Borland C++: How can a Windows service shutdown itself?

Tags: service, c++builder, shutdown

I have an old Windows Service written in Borland C++ Builder that I need to extend so that it can shutdown itself under certain conditions.

If I shutdown the service manually via the service control manager, it shuts down properly without any problems. So I thought, calling `this->DoShutdown();` would be sufficient (`this` being an instance derived from `TService`). But this leaves the service in the state "Shutting down...". I could call `ExitProcess` afterwards, but this creates an entry in the event log that the service has been shut down unexpectedly.

So what is the proper way to make a Borland C++ Windows service shut down itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoShutdown()` is called by `TService` when it receives a `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` request from the SCM while Windows is being shut down.  `DoShutdown()` is not intended to be called directly in user code.

The easiest way to have your service terminate itself is to call its `Controller()` method (either directly, or via its global `ServiceController()` function), passing either `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` or `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` in the `CtrlCode` parameter.  Let the service handle the request as if it had come from the SCM, so it can act accordingly.